# Spring Cloud Contracts arithmentic function using fromRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-contract

I'm using Spring Cloud Contracts version 2.1.1.
I understand that I can use some value from the original request to validate against some value in the response, and I can use it within another string (i.e. not as is, but concatenated with other strings):

```
response {
    status 200
    body(
        message: "Hello, ${fromRequest().body('$.name')}!",
    )
}
```

What if I wanted to used some arithmetic on a numeric json value from the request, i.e. validate that response has this value incremented:

```
response {
    status 200
    body(
        result: ${fromRequest().body('$.count')} + 1
    )
}
```

Or, maybe even two numeric values added, e.g.:

```
response {
    status 200
    body(
        result: ${fromRequest().query('num1')} + ${fromRequest().query('num2')}
    )
}
```

Obviously the two last snippets are not valid, but illustrate what I'm looking for. Is this somehow possible with current Spring Cloud Contracts?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not valid. The question is why do you want to test that logic. From the point of view of contract testing you should maybe only check that there's a number there?

Comment: I kinda understand what you're trying to say, but let's look at it this way. If I can manipulate strings from request, why shouldn't I be able to manipulate numbers?

Comment: You can reference them. We're using handlebars underneath. If you can do such operations using handlebars then that will work. You can check the yaml contract syntax on how to use the handlebars syntax

Comment: I do not see that this is currently possible even with handlebars. But maybe it _is_ possible, and I'm missing something. For example, `byCommand` looked promising, but I do not see a way to pass `fromRequest` to the method. If I'm missing something, can you provide a code snippet?